# When to write a Custom Kernel Module

Tags: network-programming, kernel-module

Problem Statement:
I have a very high bandwidth data link that is UDP based. The source of this data is not configurable, and sends on UDP a stream of datagrams. We have code that uses the standard methods for receiving data on the UDP socket that works adequately. I wanted to know if

1. Does there exist a command interface to extract multiple UDP datagrams at  a time? to improve efficiency?
2. If one doesn't exist, does it make sense to create a kernel module to provide the capability?

I am a novice, and i wanted to understand what thought process has to happen when writing your own kernel module seems appropriate. I know that such a surgical procedure isn't meant to done lightly, but there must be a set of criteria where that action is prudent. Maybe not in my case, but in general.

Answer (score 0):

**HW / Kernel Module Perspective**

A typical network adapter these days would be capable of distributing received packets across multiple *hardware* Rx queues thus letting the host run multiple *software* Rx queues bound to different CPU cores reading out packets in parallel. From a *single* HW/SW queue perspective, the host may *poll* it for new packets (see [Linux NAPI](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/napi)), with each poll ideally yielding a *batch* of packets, and, alternatively, the host may still use interrupt-driven approach for Rx signalling with [interrupt coalescing](https://01.org/linux-interrupt-moderation) turned on for improved efficiency.

Existing NIC drivers in Linux kernel strive to stick with the most performant techniques, and the kernel itself should be able to leverage all of that properly.

**Userland / Application Perspective**

There's [PACKET_MMAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/packet_mmap.html) interface provided by Linux kernel for improved Rx/Tx efficiency on the application side. Long story short, an application can set up a memory buffer shared between the kernel- and userspace and read out incoming packets from it, ideally in batches, or *blocks*, thus avoiding costly kernel-to-userspace copies and context switches so customary when using regular methods.

For added efficiency, the application may have multiple sockets bound to the NIC in separate threads / processes and demand that packet reception be load balanced across these sockets (see `AF_PACKET fanout mode` description).

**DPDK Perspective**

[Kernel bypass framework](https://www.dpdk.org/) that allows an application to seize full control of a network adapter by means of a vendor-specific *poll-mode driver*, or *PMD*, effectively running in userspace as part of the application and by its very nature not needing any kernel-to-userspace copies, context switches and, most likely, locking. Multi-queue receive operation, load balancing (round robin, [RSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/introduction-to-receive-side-scaling), you name it) and more cutting edge offloads are likely to be available, too (it's vendor specific).

**Summary**

The short of it, given the fact that multiple network acceleration techniques already exist, one need never write their own kernel module to solve the problem in question. By the looks of it, your application, which, as you say, uses *standard methods*, is not aware of `PACKET_MMAP` technique. So I'd be tempted to suggest looking at this one closely. DPDK approach might require that the application be effectively re-implemented from scratch, so I would first go for `PACKET_MMAP` approach as a low-hanging fruit.